# Нет перевода справки «What is Flair?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, визитка

Появилась новая страница справки, требующая перевода:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/flair

Comment: Спасибо! Обновил страничку, немного откорректировав предложенный перевод (чтобы тот был более похож на исходный вариант).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а что если сделать прямую ссылку на страницу визитки, а не на настройки?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky дефис длинный надо еще.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, ссылку, я обновлю публикацию.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вот же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но, может быть, не стоит. Есть нюанс для неавторизованных юзеров.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Что такое «визитка»?

Визитка - это изображение, на котором отображены ваши обобщённые достижения (репутация, количество полученных знаков, иконки сайтов с наибольшим вкладом), которое вы можете использовать на других сайтах.

Пример визитки с достижениями на конкретном сайте сети:

[image: Визитка]

Если вы участвуете сразу в нескольких сообществах Stack Exchange, вы можете похвастаться обобщённой визиткой:

[image: Визитка]

Более подробную информацию вы можете найти на соответствующей странице [настроек профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flair).

Comment: Id в ссылках меркнут перед этим :)

Comment: Кстати, вроде же был где-то этот перевод. Там еще было про"ценную штуковину"

Comment: @älёxölüt в настройках профиля.

Comment: @älёxölüt вы можете пикчи заменить на свои, я не гордый :D

Comment: смотря что понимать под "свои" :)

Comment: Нашёл, кстати, [профиль](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10/sneakers-otoole) из оригинальной статьи. Отладочный юзер.

Comment: У нас можно духа подставить. Хотя, тогда в визитке, которая суммарная по сети, будет пусто =/

Comment: Или дембеля....

Comment: А где ссылки на ютюб, кстати?

Comment: @älёxölüt там какая-то зарубежная чушь, которая местным будет непонятна.

Comment: Так локализуем!

Comment: @älёxölüt так можно, да.

Comment: Ссылку на Ютюб оставил. Буду рад заменить на что–то более подходящее, согласно вашим рекомендациям.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky видео вообще не вяжется с сабжем. Флаер вы добровольно используете, а в видео упор на принудительном базисе. Поэтому, я бы вообще его убрал из справки. Но да, само видео милое. Дженнифер Энистон няша.

Comment: @Suvitruf На мой взгляд у скаутских знаков отличия и у знаком на SO много общего. Правда, подобрать аналог на русском довольно сложно будет, так как у нас движение скаутов было запрещено какое–то время в прошлом, если я верно помню.